# Ant: not able to find tools.jar

Tags: java

when I type Ant in command line.. 
I get following error..

Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` looks like it is pointing to a *JRE* - the `tools.jar` is part of the *JDK* not the *JRE*.

Change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to a *JDK* and *ANT* will work.